# Why do I have a null pointer exception when the value prints?

Tags: android, logging, nullpointerexception

I am obtaining a string from an image (my own defined class) object. This is the block of code where the error is occurring, on the 4th line (Log):

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {

        Image image = imageList.get(i);
        Log.d("", image.getDate());
        String[] date = image.getDate().split(" ");
```

Then in the console it prints out the date value in the 1st line, so what is the problem?

```
03-17 12:22:09.054  20832-20832/com.example.sanj.flowt D/﹕ 30 08 2014
03-17 12:22:09.054  20832-20832/com.example.sanj.flowt D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-17 12:22:09.054  20832-20832/com.example.sanj.flowt W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415cddb8)
03-17 12:22:09.054  20832-20832/com.example.sanj.flowt E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sanj.flowt, PID: 20832
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Comment: You have to set a TAG and a String...for example: Log.d("LOG_KEY","Date:"+image.getDate());

Comment: there is some println code which is throwing error, can you share that also

Comment: @Fahim, this error message is also thrown for a Log

Comment: I believe Log prints the value for (example) index 0. But image at index 1 does not have any Date.

Comment: Thank you for the input guys, but the problem lied within my SQLite database. It was muddled up, causing some values not to be entered. The code above works perfectly fine.

Comment: So basically, @dit was correct in solving the answer so thank you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be saying that the NPE is thrown within the `Log.d` call here:

```
Log.d("", image.getDate());
```

It means that `image.getDate()` is returning `null`.

However, I am rather suspicious of the evidence you are providing here.  According to the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html) for `android.media.Image`, there isn't a `getDate()` method.

Comment: author of question gives log and there is `com.example.sanj.flowt D/﹕ 30 08 2014` so it is printing well without tag

Comment: Except that the author >>said<< that the NPE was thrown "on the 4th line (Log)" ... which I understand to be the line indicated.

Comment: Besides, the log line with the date could simply be explained by a different `Image` instance that has a non-null date.  Note that the `Log.d` call is in a loop ...

Comment: I can still use the image class fine so there isn't a problem there. There was  no value however, in some of my image objects.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot split by space using `" "`, it should be e.g. `"\\s+"` (all whitespaces). note that `split` takes regexp, [doc here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

edit: wrong ans, spliting by `" "` is possible in Java, my bad :)

Comment: True that! This is java and not python to split a string using .split(' ') :D

Comment: Actually it is not true.  You **can** split using a bare space ... in Java.

Comment: and it´s still not the answer to the question. The split comes after the error that is shown in the logcat: "java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message" in Line 4 which is the Log. So, also if this is true what You said, it will not remove the error

Comment: split returns never null.

Comment: It is infact possible to use split(" ") my friend ;)

Comment: ok, my bad, you are right. so one and only proper piece of my answer is `split` taking regexp... edit added

Answer (score 0):

Also simple, You have to set a string:

```
 Log.d("LOG_KEY","Date:"+image.getDate());
```

this depends on the type that get returned. For example, if image.getDate() would return a String type, then You don´t need to do it like I´ve shown (if You are sure that it doesn´t return null). But if it returns something else, You have to. This is how it is described in the API, the second Parameter must be a String:

[developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#d%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

If You do it like this and image.getDate() returns null, no exception is thrown. Then the output would be: "Date:null", if this method returns null. That´s a secure way to do it.

whatever image is, like Stepehn C. said, Image has no method getDate(), so I suspect You have made a custom class that´s called Image. That should not be done, because there is an android class that´s called Image

Comment: You do not have to set a string. I haven't done it once throughout the project and everything prints perfectly fine. Thank you though.

Comment: that is correct. Although this didn't solve the problem, nice one for giving a better explanation in case others come across this and learn something.